# SQL Query add default value

Tags: mysql, sql, bash

I have an SQL query that is a load of +1000 records to a table. We have added a new field to discriminate a certain value and I need to add it to the query. Is there any command that automates the process? It would add a default value at the end of all insert.

Update:The field already has a default value of 0. The query with these inserts must specify that field to 1. I need a way to add that default value to those specific inserts.

Update2:The query type is INSERT INTO xx(xx,xx,x,x,x,x) VALUES (x,x,x,x), (x,xx,x,x,x), ----> add new value at the end

Update 3:The answers are not valid since I have more than 1000 insertions, I cannot manually add that field

Comment: You can specify a default value for the new _column_.

Comment: `automates the process` => what do you mean here ?

Comment: *I have an SQL query that is a load of +1000 records to a table.* What type of query? LOAD DATA INFILE? INSERT .. SELECT? something else?

Comment: update question

Comment: Need clear information in your question.

Comment: The query type is INSERT INTO xx(xx,xx,x,x,x,x)  
   VALUES (x,x,x,x),
    (x,xx,x,x,x), ----> add new value at the end

Comment: For this query type you must edit each data block in VALUES clause (and fields list in INSERT INTO clause) and add proper fieldname and value. *I cannot manually add that field* Do it using any text editor (replace `)` with `,1)`).

Answer (score 1):

You can change the default value before an after the inserts:

```
alter table t alter col set default = 1;
```

Then change it back or drop it afterwards:

```
alter table t alter col set default = 0;
alter table t alter col drop default;
```

You won't have to modify the `insert` statements, unless the column is already part of them (because an explicit value would override the default).

Answer (score 0):

You can either set 'Default' value for that column in your table.
If it is a Boolean, set default expression to False or True. Similarly works for char or integer or timestamp.

But, if you want to set it only via Query for some reason, just add that value to the query. Why not!

Example Query:

```
    INSERT INTO tab(c1,c2,...descriminate_column) VALUES(v1,v2,...FALSE)
```

or

```
    INSERT INTO tab(c1,c2,...descriminate_column) VALUES(v1,v2,...NULL)
```

or

```
    INSERT INTO tab(c1,c2,...descriminate_column) VALUES(v1,v2,...'default_val')
```

**UPDATE AS PER YOUR UPDATED QUESTION:**

As I understood from your update, you have a Boolean column with default False, and you want to set that column to True only for some of the Inserts in a loop and you want to include the column name for all queries.
If that's the case, you can use the below query to insert default value:

```
INSERT INTO tab(c1, c2, c3, c4, discriminate_column) VALUES(204, 'test', '1.2.2.3', 'today', default)
```

**UPDATE2:**

> INSERT INTO xx(xx,xx,x,x,x,x) VALUES (x,x,x,x), (x,xx,x,x,x)

No of columns mentioned and number of values should always be equal. If you want to leave the default values for some queries, put `default` for that insert.

> INSERT INTO xx(xx,xx,x,x,x,x) VALUES (x,x,x,x,default), (x,xx,x,x,x)

Comment: But how do I automate that process to add the default value to all inserts in my query. That is Values ​​(x, x, x), (x, x, x), (x, x, x), (x, x, x), (x, x, x), and so n times I must add said field at the end. It is not a single insert, but 1000 insert that I already have generated in a file.

Comment: @Diego I know that it has been so long since the question, but may I know what happened with this problem? To be honest, I did not understand the question exactly.

Answer (score 0):

If it's an `insert...select`:

```
insert into MyTable (col1, col2, ..., thenewcolumn)
select column1, column2, ..., 1
from somewhere
```

If it's a regular insert, just put `1` into the value:

```
insert into MyTable (col1, col2, ..., thenewcolumn)
values
(12, 'abc',...,1)
```